# How to fixed the value in input field and also set default zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

now i doing a form that can add product to outlet.This form is create at the outletproduct page

So when i click to a product info page have a button (add product to outlet) then go to the form which located at outletproduct page. Now i need to set these things

1.I have create the form out but at the product name field there i need to display product name i choose to be fixed and cannot be change.(Example, click on the product fish then click button then the product name should be fish.)

2.The selling_price and last_cost will need to show the product price and cost in the input field there but this can be change(Example, at product page price is $2 and cost is $1, then here the input field will be selling_price $2 and last_cost $1.)

i have try do but it won't work.

I have update some pic about UI.

OutletProduct Controller

```
 class OutletProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @outlet_product = OutletProduct.new
   @product = Product.all
   @outlet = Outlet.all
   @category = Category.all
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
   @outlet_product = OutletProduct.new(outlet_product_params)
   @category_id = Category.all
   @outlet_id = Outlet.all
   @product_id = Product.all
    if @outlet_product.save
    flash[:success] = "Succesful create!"
    redirect_to @outlet_product
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end

 def edit
 end

 def outlet_product_params
 params.require(:outlet_product).permit(:product_id, :outlet_id, :quantity,
                                       :selling_price ,:last_cost)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add product to outlet</h1>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <%= form_with(model: @outlet_product, local: true) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :product_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :@product.name ,class: "form-select" %>

  <%= f.label :quantity %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantity%>

  <%= f.label :selling_price %>
  <%= f.number_field :selling_price, @product.price , class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :last_cost %>
  <%= f.number_field :last_cost,@product.cost, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :outlet_id %>
  <%= f.select(:outlet_id, Outlet.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id] }, {class: "form-select"}) %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

OutletProduct migration in schema

```
create_table "outlet_products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "outlet_id"
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.decimal "selling_price"
  t.decimal "last_cost"
  t.decimal "quantity"
end
```

product migration in schema

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
 t.integer "quantity"
 t.integer "price"
 t.integer "category_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.decimal "cost"
end
```

[Product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR93E.png)

[Product info page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCGJI.png)]

[form page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAjF0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can define all the default values in view like below

```
<%= f.label :selling_price %>
<%= f.number_field :selling_price, 0 , class: 'form-control' %>
```

or if you wanted to keep it by default in the database, then you can make changes in migration files as below:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name", default: 'fish'
 t.integer "quantity", default: 0
 t.integer "price"
 t.integer "category_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.decimal "cost"
end
```

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, for the quantity is work but for the product is not just one product. Let say i have a list of product(shampoo,fish,cookies....) then i choose fish and i click the button(add product to outlet) then i will go to the form, at the product name there will show fish and cannot edit. if i choose cookies then at form there the product name will be cookies. How can i do this?

Comment: when you click on `choose <product_name>`, you can pass product name in params and can used it to initialize in the new action as   `@outlet_product = OutletProduct.new(name: <product_name>)`

Comment: at the controller there?

Comment: is that have any way can do it at form input field there?